# Eliminate from dmenu the programs that cannot be launched

Tags: dmenu

I use i3 with dmenu. Is it possible to prevent from showing up the programs that cannot be launched via dmenu? (e.g. top, ps, ls etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `dmenu_run` to exclude an application from appearing in `dmenu`. For example, to exclude `a2x`, add an additional process to the pipeline:

From:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmenu_path | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

To:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmenu_path | awk '!/a2x/' | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

If you wanted to exclude more than one application, you could use an `excludes` file:

```
dmenu_path | grep -v -f /path/to/dmenu_excludes | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

Comment: the file location is `/usr/bin/dmenu_run` btw everyone